# Serialization of objects and fatal error

Tags: php, session, serialization, fatal-error

Can anyone explain me, why in the session in this case we get the object with **2** properties?

```
set_error_handler('my_error_handler');

session_start();

$obj = new myclass();

$_SESSION['obj'] = $obj;

$a->b();

class myclass
{
    private $a = 1;
    private $b = 2;

    public function __sleep()
    {
        return array('a');
    }
}

function my_error_handler($code, $error, $file = NULL, $line = NULL)
{
    throw new ErrorException($error, $code, 0, $file, $line);
}
```

**UPD**: here i expect to get:
1. fatal error (*passed*)
2. object in session (in **session file**) with **1** property (*failed*)

Comment: Your question isn't clear. What are you expecting?

Comment: @Sarfraz: sorry. question updated

Comment: I'll investigate after lunch, but your scripts really shouldn't be raising fatal errors (by the way the error handler don't handle fatals)

Comment: @Artefacto: indeed, they should not. But that doesn't mean, that php should break my data if I occasionally have made a mistake during regular developing process.

Comment: "by the way the error handler don't handle fatals" -- i know it, but the error handler in such case is meaningful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for this is that a fatal error is, well, *fatal* to the engine. After it, the engine cannot call anymore functions.

Hence, in `php_var_serialize_intern` the [call to `__sleep`](http://svn.php.net/viewvc/php/php-src/tags/php_5_3_3/ext/standard/var.c?revision=301440&view=markup#l778) fails. As you can see, you don't need a fatal error, if `__sleep` had thrown an exception, or if there wasn't any `__sleep` callback at all, the behavior would be similar.

In particular, the behavior is to retrieve all the instance properties of the variable and to serialize the resulting hash table as if it belonged to an array.

I think this is a valid approach, but perhaps you think that if the call to `__sleep` fails, the serialization should just fail. You can try to [submit a feature request](http://bugs.php.net).

Comment: i've filled bug http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=52604. "I think this is a valid approach" -- it breaks my data, and it is definitely not what i'm expecting. i expect my data to be safe ;-)

Comment: so, since it is bogus/bug and it is following the current implementation - there is nothing more to discuss. if no answers will be added within next day - i will accept this answer (i will accept it in any case, but if anyone has thoughts about what should happen in my sample code - i would like to discuss)